# matplotlib.pyplot/pylab not updating figure while isinteractive(), using ipython -pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are a lot of questions about matplotlib, pylab, pyplot, ipython, so I'm sorry if you're sick of seeing this asked.  I'll try to be as specific as I can, because I've been looking through people's questions and looking at documentation for pyplot and pylab, and I still am not sure what I'm doing wrong. On with the code:

Goal: plot a figure every .5 seconds, and update the figure as soon as the plot command is called.

My attempt at coding this follows (running on ipython -pylab):

```
import time
ion()
x=linspace(-1,1,51)
plot(sin(x))
for i in range(10):
    plot([sin(i+j) for j in x])
    #see **
    print i
    time.sleep(1)
print 'Done'
```

It correctly plots each line, but not until it has exited the for loop.  I have tried forcing a redraw by putting `draw()` where `**` is, but that doesn't seem to work either.  Ideally, I'd like to have it simply add each line, instead of doing a full redraw.  If redrawing is required however, that's fine.

Additional attempts at solving:

just after `ion()`, tried adding `hold(True)` to no avail.

for kicks tried `show()` for `**`

The closest answer I've found to what I'm trying to do was at [plotting lines without blocking execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310851/plotting-lines-without-blocking-execution), but `show()` isn't doing anything.

I apologize if this is a straightforward request, and I'm looking past something so obvious.  For what it's worth, this came up while I was trying to convert matlab code from class to some python for my own use.  The original matlab (initializations removed) which I have been trying to convert follows:

```
for i=1:time
    plot(u)
    hold on
    pause(.01)
    for j=2:n-1
        v(j)=u(j)-2*u(j-1)
    end
    v(1)= pi
    u=v
end
```

Any help, even if it's just "look up this_method" would be excellent, so I can at least narrow my efforts to figuring out how to use that method.  If there's any more information that would be useful, let me know.

Comment: [You should use `pyplot.pause` rather than `time.sleep`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822762/pylab-ion-in-python-2-matplotlib-1-1-1-and-updating-of-the-plot-while-the-pro)

Comment: I had the same problem using the QT4Agg backend on Windows, I believe it is related to this [github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1646), using pyplot.pause() fixed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second answer to the question you linked provides the answer: call `draw()` after every `plot()` to make it appear immediately; for example:

```
import time
ion()
x = linspace(-1,1,51)
plot(sin(x))
for i in range(10):
    plot([sin(i+j) for j in x])
    # make it appear immediately
    draw()
    time.sleep(1)
```

If that doesn't work... try what they do on this page: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations

```
import time

ion()

tstart = time.time()               # for profiling
x = arange(0,2*pi,0.01)            # x-array
line, = plot(x,sin(x))
for i in arange(1,200):
    line.set_ydata(sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    draw()                         # redraw the canvas

print 'FPS:' , 200/(time.time()-tstart)
```

The page mentions that the `line.set_ydata()` function is the key part.

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me.  I have no doubt it's right, I'm just not sure why it's not working for me. As soon as the first one prints, I see a blank window for 10 seconds; after which all of the graphs appear.  But draw() doesn't seem to be forcing an update until it's out of the for loop.  I've just started (trying) to use matplotlib- could this be related to the "backend" I've heard about?  (I have no idea what that is =/)

Comment: @NumberOverZero - what platform are you using? (Windows/Mac/Linux...)

Comment: Weird... it works for me on 7. Okay, I'll update the answer with something else to try.

Comment: Looked promising, but no such luck.  Getting around 77fps.  I threw a pause in the main loop afterward to see if it was doing each piece at a time, using "trashvar=raw_input(":")" to pause each time for input.  Same thing, still a blank screen until the loop finishes.

Comment: :( I'm sorry - both methods work for me, I don't have any idea what's going on.

Comment: No problem, I'll keep looking and if nothing comes up, go for a fresh install when I can get my hands on another computer.  Thank you for the help, I'm sure it will work for (most) someone(s).

Answer (score 9):

```
from pylab import *
import time
ion()
tstart = time.time()               # for profiling
x = arange(0,2*pi,0.01)            # x-array
line, = plot(x,sin(x))
for i in arange(1,200):
    line.set_ydata(sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    draw()                         # redraw the canvas
    pause(0.01)
print 'FPS:' , 200/(time.time()-tstart)
ioff()
show()
```

########################
The above worked for me nicely. I ran it in spyder editor in pythonxy2.7.3 under win7 OS.
Note the `pause()` statement following `draw()` followed by `ioff()` and `show()`.

Comment: Nothing was working for me (also on win 7) until i added the pause(statement). THANKS

Answer (score 5):

had the exact same problem with ipython running on my mac. (Enthought Distribution of python 2.7 32bit on Macbook pro running snow leopard).

Got a tip from a friend at work. Run ipython from the terminal with the following arguments:

```
ipython -wthread -pylab
```

This works for me. The above python code from "Daniel G" runs without incident, whereas previously it didn't update the plot.

According to the ipython documentation:

> [-gthread, -qthread, -q4thread, -wthread, -pylab:...] They provide
> threading support for the GTK, Qt (versions 3 and 4) and WXPython
> toolkits, and for the matplotlib library.

I don't know why that is important, but it works.

hope that is helpful,
labjunky

Comment: this -wthread flag fixed a similar issue for me , with figure windows locking up on closure.  thanks!

Comment: sadly -wthread was [removed in ipython 0.11](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#eventloop-integration).  Is there any other way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441874/matplotlib-animation-either-freezes-after-a-few-frames-or-just-doesnt-work/3669265#3669265) I posted here to a similar question. I could generate your animation without problems using only the **GTKAgg** backend. To do this, you need to add this line to your script (I think before importing pylab):

```
matplotlib.use('GTkAgg')
```

and also install PyGTK.