# Matplotlib plotting in linux vs. mswindows

Tags: linux, windows, plot, matplotlib

I'm trying to produce a plot in a loop that updates itself every iteration. Working in a linux environment with python 2.6.6 I have it working, but when I run the same code in windows XP with python 2.7.3 it fails. Minimal code that has produced this error for me is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
plt.figure(1)

for i in range(10):
   plt.clf()
   plt.plot(i,i**2,'bo')
   plt.axis([-1,10, -1, 90])
   plt.draw()
```

In linux I see a blue dot that moves itself along a parabola. In MSwindows I get an empty window to begin with and then a plot with a point at (9,81) appears. This seems pretty straightforward, but maybe I'm missing something small. Any suggestions?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, and I think you might try looking at using the `animation` library instead http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example.html

Comment: I tried looking into the `animation` library, but it wasn't really what I was looking for. Maybe I misunderstood its use, but it seemed to collect all the figures during execution, but animate them only once all plots were collected. I was looking for more of a real time data display than an animation at the end of data collection. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13601492/1738884

It turns out in windows all I needed was to add a `plt.pause(.01)` after the `plt.draw()` and my plot updated every iteration as desired. So the simplified working code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
plt.figure(1)

for i in range(10):
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(i,i**2,'bo')
    plt.axis([-1,10, -1, 90])
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.01)
```

Comment: Neato, I wasn't familiar with this. (Reference for the pause method: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=pause#matplotlib.pyplot.pause)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link, I should have put it in the answer.