# matplotlib qt imshow animate

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, animated

Does imshow animation work with the qt-backend? The following works fine in non-qt but does not animate using qt - just shows the last frame:

```
img = standard_normal((40,40))
image =imshow(img,interpolation='nearest',animated=True)
for k in range(1,10): 
     img = standard_normal((40,40)) 
     image.set_data(img) 
     draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add a `pause` in the loop after the draw or use the `matplotlib.animation` module [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) [(tutorial)](http://jakevdp.github.com/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/).

possibly related [matplotlib.pyplot/pylab not updating figure while isinteractive(), using ipython -pylab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604119/matplotlib-pyplot-pylab-not-updating-figure-while-isinteractive-using-ipython):

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a look at that but it looks like for using the qt backend the call to:

```
QApplication.ProcessEvents()
```

updates the imshow plot.