# How to update pcolor in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I plot information from a 2D array with pcolor. however, the information in the array is changed over the iterations, and I want to update the color map dynamically, in order to visualize the changes in real time. How can I do it in the most simple way?

Edit - example:

```
from __future__ import division
from pylab import *
import random

n = 50 # number of iterations
x = arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y = arange(0, 10, 0.1)
T = zeros([100,100]) # 10/0.1 = 100
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y)

"""initial conditions"""
for x in range(100):
 for y in range(100):
  T[x][y] = random.random()

pcolor(X, Y, T, cmap=cm.hot, vmax=abs(T).max(), vmin=0)
colorbar()
axis([0,10,0,10])
show() # colormap of the initial array

"""main loop"""

for i in range(n):
 for x in range(100):
  for y in range(100):
   T[x][y] += 0.1 # here i do some calculations, the details are not important

 # here I want to update the color map with the new array (T)
```

Thanks

Comment: possibly helpful [10944621](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Can you use `imshow` instead of `pcolor`?

Comment: Can you also post a minimal example of what you are doing and any (partially) working code?  It makes in much easier to help you.

Comment: thanks, but I want to do it with the "pcolor" command. I can also use imshow.

Comment: why?  `imshow` has an almost trivial method for updating the data, `pcolor` returns a `PolyCollection` which is a bit harder to update

Comment: it was a response for runnerup. I can do it with imshow also (but don't know how..(-: )

Comment: As a side not, you can replace your nested loops (over `x` and `y`) with `T += .1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `imshow` ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow)):

```
# figure set up
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax_lst = ax_lst.ravel()

#fake data
data = rand(512, 512)
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 512)
X, Y = meshgrid(x, x)

data2 = np.sin(X ** 2 + Y **2)
# plot the first time#fake data

im = ax_lst[0].imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', 
                            origin='bottom', 
                            aspect='auto', # get rid of this to have equal aspect
                            vmin=np.min(data),
                            vmax=np.max(data), 
                            cmap='jet')

cb = plt.colorbar(im)

pc = ax_lst[1].pcolor(data)
cb2 = plt.colorbar(pc)
```

To updata the data with imshow, just set the data array, and it takes care of all of the normalization and color mapping for you:

```
# update_data (imshow)
im.set_data(data2) 
plt.draw()
```

To do the same with thing with `pcolor` you need to do the normalization and color mapping your self (and guess the row-major vs column major right):

```
my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
#my_nom = # you will need to scale your read data between [0, 1]
new_color = my_cmap(data2.T.ravel())
pc.update({'facecolors':new_color})

draw()
```

Comment: Thanks are good, upvote and accept are better ;) (also see edit re colorbar)

Comment: last question: How can i limit the the x and y axes? imshow does not allow me to write imshow(X,Y,T) but only imshow(T).

Comment: You want to use the `extent` kwarg

Comment: hmmm...you said that imshow should do the color mapping for me. Howerver it does not happen, the colors do not change over time. Should I write some command in order to update it?

Comment: @user1767774 You might need a `plt.pause()` in your loop to make sure the canvas actually updates.  Other than that, post a new with what code you are using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595566/matplotlib-qt-imshow-animate/13802936#13802936

Answer (score 3):

I have here a simple example how to update `ax.pcolor` (or rather its faster cousin `ax.pcolormesh`) during a simulation.

```
def make_movie(fig, meshData, conc, fout='writer_test.mp4',
           dpi=150, metadata={}):
    '''
    Make a movie (on disk) starting from a first image generated with matplotlib,
    by updating only the values that were dispayed with ax.pcolormesh(...).

    Parameters
    ----------
    meshData: mesh as returned by ax.pcolormesh()
    conc: obj returned by readUCN
        computed concentrations
    fout: str
        name of output file, with or without '.mp4' extension.
    dpi: int
        dots per inch of output movie
    metadata: dict
        passed on to FFMpegWriter.savings(fout, ...)
    '''
    plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg'

    from matplotlib.animation import FFMpegWriter

    writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=15, metadata=metadata)

    totims = conc.totim # get times of computed concentrations

    with writer.saving(fig, fout, dpi):
        for totim in totims:
            C = conc.at_t(totim)[:, 0, :] # 3D -->  2D Xsection concentrations
            #newcolors = cmap(norm(C.ravel()))
            #meshData.update({'facecolors': newcolors})
            meshData.update({'array': C.ravel()}) # reset array to new conc.
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
            writer.grab_frame()
```

The lines starting with `#newcolors` and `#meshData.update` are as suggested by @tacaswell above. The line starting with `meshdata.udate({array ...` replaces them. It just updates the data without computing the new facecolors. The last method is simpler and works just as well. Transposing the data array is not necessary.

Comment: All you need is `meshData.update({"array":C.ravel()})` (and some sort of draw call) but this should be the answer people use and refer to now.  FWIW, I ran some basic timing and the update function is ~50-100x faster than the original pcolormesh call for my simple 100x100 test case. A better answer might be simplified to remove the extra movie related code work (though I learned from the movie code too, so thanks for it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect events to your figure and call a specific function on that event. In the following I took an example of the `matplotlib` documentation and added a function `ontype`. This is called when `1` is pressed on the keyboard. Then `X * func3()` is called. `Ontype` is bound to the figure with `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event',ontype)`. In a similar way you could fire regular events time dependent.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
See pcolor_demo2 for an alternative way of generating pcolor plots
using imshow that is likely faster for large grids
"""
from __future__ import division
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from pylab import *

def ontype(event):
    ''' function that is called on key event (press '1')'''
    if event.key == '1':
        print 'It is working'
        fig.gca().clear()
        # plot new function X * func3(X, Y) 
        Z = X * func3(X, Y) 
        pcolor(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.RdBu, vmax=abs(Z).max(), vmin=-abs(Z).max())
        fig.canvas.draw()

def func3(x,y):
    return (1- x/2 + x**5 + y**3)*exp(-x**2-y**2)


# make these smaller to increase the resolution
dx, dy = 0.05, 0.05

x = arange(-3.0, 3.0001, dx)
y = arange(-3.0, 3.0001, dy)
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y)

Z = func3(X, Y)

fig=figure(figsize=(16,8))

# connect ontype to canvas
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event',ontype)

pcolor(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.RdBu, vmax=abs(Z).max(), vmin=-abs(Z).max())
colorbar()
axis([-3,3,-3,3])

show()
```