# How to continue executing a python script while showing a plot/figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to detach matplotlib plots so that the computation can continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458209/is-there-a-way-to-detach-matplotlib-plots-so-that-the-computation-can-continue)

I use python with matplotlib for scientific programming. But whenever I use the command `show()` to display a plot, the script just stops there. I have to close the figure window for the script to continue executing. Is there a way to keep the script running while the figure window is open, just like in Matlab?

Comment: Coincidentally facing the same problem RIGHT NOW!! +1 (some matplotlib doctor could shed some light over this topic, for us mere mortals :o(

Comment: Are you running your code in interactive mode?

Comment: Yes, I tried the _interactive mode_ (I'm not sure what it is), with the `ion()` command. It didn't make any difference.

Comment: Try using interactive mode with `show` replaced with `draw`.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like there's only one thread running, and so the rest of your script can't continue until the show function returns, which won't happen until the figure is closed. Should be relatively simple to call that show function in a newly created thread, which would allow the rest of your script to keep running. I'd look into the `threading` python module.