# How to exit a main program from the Multiprocessing Process in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am spawning 3 processes using multiprocessing.process and waiting for them to complete. If one of them fails then i want to stop all other processes and also the main program. But when i use sys.exit the execution is only stopping just the process and not the main program. Here is the snippet of the code.

```
proc1=process(function1)
proc2=process(function2)
proc3=process(function3)
proc1.start
proc2.start
proc3.start
proc1.join
proc2.join
proc3.join
```

.
.
.

I am running some tasks in functions 1,2 and 3. I have a condition in each function to check the returncode of the task and if the returncode is not success then i would like to stop proc1,proc2 and proc3 and stop execution of the main program. When i execute sys.exit inside the function it just comes out of that process and not the main program.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work you need to have communication between the worker processes and the main process. Probably the simplest way is to use `multiprocessing.Event`.

*Before* starting the processes, create a pair of `multiprocessing.Event`. Give them meaningful names like `stop_main` and `stop_workers`. For portability, one should give add these `Event`s to the arguments given for the `Process` target.

A worker process should call `stop_main.set()` when it wants the main program to exit. A worker process should also call `stop_workers.is_set()` regularly and exit when this returns `True`.

After the main process starts all the workers it should keep polling `stop_main.is_set()`. When that returns `True` it should call `stop_workers.set()`, `join` the workers and exit.

**Updated:**

Edited to make it shorter and hopefully make it work on ms-windows.

An example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


def worker(num, sw, sm):
    if num == 5:
        print('This is worker', num)
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Worker', num, 'signalling main program to quit')
        sm.set()
    while not sw.is_set():
        print('This is worker', num)
        time.sleep(0.7)
    else:
        print('Worker', num, 'signing off..')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stop_worker = mp.Event()
    stop_main = mp.Event()

    workers = [mp.Process(target=worker, args=(n, stop_worker, stop_main))
               for n in range(1, 6)]
    for w in workers:
        w.start()
    while not stop_main.is_set():
        time.sleep(1)
    print('MAIN: Received stop event')
    print('MAIN: Sending stop event to workers')
    stop_worker.set()
    for c, w in enumerate(workers, start=1):
        w.join()
        print('worker', c, 'joined')
```

It runs like this:

> ```
> This is worker 1
> This is worker 2
> This is worker 3
> This is worker 4
> This is worker 5
> This is worker 2
> This is worker 3
> This is worker 1
> This is worker 4
> Worker 5 signalling main program to quit
> This is worker 5
> This is worker 2
> This is worker 3
> This is worker 1
> This is worker 4
> This is worker 5
> MAIN: Received stop event
> MAIN: Sending stop event to workers
> Worker 3 signing off..
> Worker 1 signing off..
> Worker 2 signing off..
> worker 1 joined
> worker 2 joined
> worker 3 joined
> Worker 4 signing off..
> worker 4 joined
> Worker 5 signing off..
> worker 5 joined
> ```

Comment: dep_event = Event()

proc1=process(function1, args= dep_event)
proc1.start

while True
   if dep_event.is_set() == "True":
      sys.exit(1)

....
.....
....
....


function1(depp_event)
....
...
....
depp_event.set()

I tested the above code and still it doesn't end the main program

Comment: I am able to able to fix the issue and now able to stop the main program using the events. Thanks a lot for your timely help. But i can creating a subprocess(shell = True enabled) from this process, So if i terminate this process it is not killing the subprocess , So how do  i make sure that i kill both the process and subprocess before exiting the main program.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution. You lose all communication to the launched process once `__main__` exits, but that's ok for my use-case with matplotlib. Just close the window or, as you mentioned, close the shell.

The [example script is located in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56982302/7621907).