# Python real-time updating plot with multiple (configurable) figures and multiple (configurable) subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, jquery-animate

I'm basically trying to create a configurable number of figures and a configurable number of subplots on each figure. And then go retrieve data once a minute or so and update those plots.

If I do plot.show() the plot comes up and seems to wait for the figures to be close before executing any other lines of code. So I can't just tell it to wait a minute and replot.

If I go with the fig.show() it comes up and closes too quickly.

So I'm at a loss for how to do this properly where I have a plot that stays open for a minute or so (would like to also configure) and then updates. And it needs to be done for a configurable number of figures and subplots.

I've been working in pyplot and keep trying to define a 2-d array of line objects. But I think I'm going about this the wrong way since all I really want to do is replot data every minute or so.

Here are more details of what I'm working on:

1) I have zip files filled with xml data that gets updated in real time (once a minute the xml data is added to the zip file for that day
2) I want to find certain xml data and write only new data to a sqlite DB
3) Find data in the sqlite DB and make a plot of it. 
4) The number of figures needs to be configurable (1 or 2 at the moment but perhaps more in the future) and the number of subplots on each figure should also be configurable. 
5) In real-time, find the new data and replot or animate it.

1 - 4 are completely done and I can plot the data for designated periods of time... just not replot it.

Hope this made sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your design is getting stuck because you are trying to do 2 tasks in 1 thread: showing a GUI, and updating the background data for it. A GUI in python takes an entire thread to run itself, which is why your program stops, or "**blocks**" continuing on when you call this function.  What you need to do is use matplotlib's "**non-blocking**" features to allow your program to update. [This similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4149491/5484656) offers several answers explaining how to use the concept of a non-blocking plot.