# Plot freezing only in Pycharm's "Python Console" during ipdb debug session

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, pycharm

I am using Windows 7 64-bit with PyCharm 2016.3.2, build #PY-163.10154.50, built on December 28, 2016.

I have a very simple script `Test.py` which is shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipdb

plt.ion()

x = [1, 2, 3]
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()

ipdb.set_trace()
```

When I execute the script from the Windows Terminal using the command `python Test.py`, the script runs fine: I am taken to the ipdb console, where I can create and plot new variables while interacting with the generated plot. Additionally, if I run the script by first opening iPython in the Windows Terminal and calling `ipython` and then calling `exec(compile(open('Test.py', "rb").read(), 'Test3.py', 'exec'))` in the iPython console, it still runs fine. Finally, when I execute the script in either of these ways from the Terminal interface in PyCharm, it still runs fine.

I run into issues when I want to run the script from the Python Console interface in PyCharm. The console opens with a message

> "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe" "E:\Program Files
>   (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py"

and shows me that it is running IPython 5.1.0 with Python 3.5.2 | Anaconda 4.2.0 as the interpreter. When I use the same `exec` command above in this console,  the code runs up 'til the breakpoint, but the figure does not render and the figure window freezes. Please see the figure below:

[image]

If I use `plt.pause(10)`, the figure renders but freezes again after 10 seconds. During these 10 seconds, I can interact with the figure, but I cannot create or probe any variables with code (I am prompted by a PyCharm pop-up that the previous command is still running). Moreover, when `plt.pause` finishes, I receive a warning:

> E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py:2437: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function specific to this GUI is implemented
>     warnings.warn(str, mplDeprecation)

At any time, if I try to make new figures from the ipdb console, they also do not render and the window remains frozen until I execute `plt.pause` (i.e. `plt.pause` must be executed after any figure is created or modified).

How can I fix this issue so I can utilize the convenience of the Python Console interface in PyCharm while interacting with plots and creating/modifying variables?

Comment: I have the same question here, I'm using spyder IDE under Windows, matplotlib's image window showns as standard alone window(not the inline window under the ipython). I have add the `plt.ion() # enables interactive mode` followed the way suggest here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/458295/154911 , but still no luck.