# Why child process (daemon=True) not exiting when main process exit in python?

Tags: python, process, daemon

Here is the official explanation of `daemon` flag in python multiprocessing:

> When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes.

By my understanding, the parent process will kill its children whose daemon flag is set to be True when it exits.

Below is the code I used to prove my guess. But the result is different.

```
import multiprocessing


def child():
    while True:
        pass


for x in xrange(1, 4):
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=child, args=())
    proc.daemon=True
    proc.start()


while True:
    pass
```

The above starts 4 child processes and one main process.
I killed the main process but the 4 children did not exit.

So why are they not terminated by main since the daemon is set to be true?

Comment: Which OS are you on? When I try on Windows, I get a bunch of process related errors.

Comment: I ran this on my Linux system and have added an answer, check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Notes**:

- The use of *xrange* the implies *Python **2***
- `xrange(1, 4)` will yield 3 values not 4 (so, there will only be 3 children)

This is not quite how things work. The doc ([[Python 2.Docs]: multiprocessing - daemon](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon)) should probably be more specific.

The thing is that *multiprocessing* registers a *cleanup function* to kill all its *deamonic* children when exiting. That is done via [[Python 2.Docs]: atexit - Exit handlers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html#module-atexit) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> **Note**: The functions registered via this module ***are not called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python***, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when [os._exit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit) is called.

You don't handle the *TERM* signal (sent by default by the *kill* command), therefore the cleanup function is not called by the main process (leaving its children running).

I modified your code to better illustrate the behavior.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import multiprocessing
import os
import sys
import time


print_text_pattern = "Output from process {:s} - pid: {:d}, ppid: {:d}"


def child(name):
    while True:
        print(print_text_pattern.format(name, os.getpid(), os.getppid()))
        time.sleep(1)


def main(*argv):
    procs = list()
    for x in xrange(1, 3):
        proc_name = "Child{:d}".format(x)
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=child, args=(proc_name,))
        proc.daemon = True #x % 2 == 0
        print("Process {:s} daemon: {:}".format(proc_name, proc.daemon))
        procs.append(proc)

    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()

    counter = 0
    while counter < 3:
        print(print_text_pattern.format("Main", os.getpid(), os.getppid()))
        time.sleep(1)
        counter += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- Changed the way how children processes are spawned a bit: all of them are created 1<sup>st</sup>, and only then started
- Added some *print* calls from each process, to track their activity in the *StdOut* - also added some *time.sleep* calls (1 second), to avoid producing too much output
- **Most important** - the main process no longer runs forever. At some point it exits gracefully (after 3 cycles - due to *counter* variable), and there's when the behavior that I mentioned earlier kicks in.
  This could also have been possible by intercepting the *TERM* signal (and others that can be explicitly be sent by the *kill* command) and performing the cleanup then - in that way the children would be killed as well when killing the main process - but that's more complicated
- I simplified things a bit so that only 2 children are spawned
- Moved everything in a *main* function (for structure) enclosed in a `if __name__ == "__main__":` conditional, so the processes are not spawned if you **import** the module
- Give different values *proc.daemon* for each child then monitor the output and `ps -ef | grep "code00.py"` output
- Added an argument (*name*) to *child* *func*, but that's only for display purposes

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> python2 ./code00.py
> Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] 064bit on linux2
>
> Process Child1 daemon: True
> Process Child2 daemon: True
> Output from process Main - pid: 1433, ppid: 1209
> Output from process Child1 - pid: 1434, ppid: 1433
> Output from process Child2 - pid: 1435, ppid: 1433
> Output from process Main - pid: 1433, ppid: 1209
> Output from process Child2 - pid: 1435, ppid: 1433
> Output from process Child1 - pid: 1434, ppid: 1433
> Output from process Main - pid: 1433, ppid: 1209
> Output from process Child1 - pid: 1434, ppid: 1433
> Output from process Child2 - pid: 1435, ppid: 1433
> Output from process Child1 - pid: 1434, ppid: 1433
> Output from process Child2 - pid: 1435, ppid: 1433
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Very well explained! Take my upvote :) So in short, you mean to say, that OP is not handling the TERM signal, when they let the main process run indefinitely until they abruptly kill it? And that is why the cleanup function for child processes are not called?

Comment: @nj2237: Thank you. Yes, if the OP would handle *TERM*, and inside the handler would call the cleanup function that *multiprocessing* registers, the code from the question would behave as expected.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. So calling `sys.exit()` in the main process also handles TERM, which is why it worked for me.

Comment: @nj2237 I don't claim that. `sys.exit` gracefully exits the process, and the `atexit` funcs are executed. I am not sure whether it sends the signal or not (didn't dig that deep into the code).

Comment: okay, I will edit my answer back. Also I checked this - https://pymotw.com/2/atexit/index.html and looks like calling `sys.exit` will also register the `atexit` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct and your code to test this also works.

I just added some sleep statements to debug the output (without `sleep`, it is difficult to infer from the huge output of prints):

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys

print("main")

def child():
    while True:
        print("child")
        time.sleep(3)

for x in xrange(1, 4):
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=child, args=())
    proc.daemon=True
    proc.start()

time.sleep(7)
print("exit")
sys.exit() # this exits the main process
```

Now, when I ran this script, and when it was running, I did a `ps aux` and could see four processes running from this script. After 7 seconds, when I did `ps aux` again, I could no more see those processes running - which means:

> When the main process exited, it terminated all of its daemonic child processes.

After that, I also set the `proc.daemon` to `False`, and ran the script once again. This time, even after 7 seconds, when I did a `ps aux`, I could still see the child processes running (since they are non-daemonic now, they do not exit even after main process terminates).

So this works as expected - let me know if you still have an issue here.

**Edit 1:**
Thanks to @CristiFati for pointing out the original cleanup issue.
This code works because calling `sys.exit()` also registers the `atexit` callbacks as elaborated [here](https://pymotw.com/2/atexit/index.html).