# How the child process can act as a daemon after the main process is finished

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-daemon

I want to know that even main process is existing, How can I make child processes to keep running?
And pool case also can do this?

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process

def doubler(number):
    result = number * 2
    proc_name = current_process().name
    print('{0} doubled to {1} by: {2}'.format( number, result, proc_name))
    time.sleep(2)
    print('eixt{0}'.format(proc_name))

def doubler1():
    print("manse!!!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
    procs = []

    for index, number in enumerate(numbers):
        proc = Process(target=doubler, args=(number,))
        #proc.daemon = True
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    proc = Process(target=doubler1)
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

    print('main process exit')

   # for proc in procs:
   #     proc.join()
```

Comment: Your main process does not exit. Even if it prints that exit message, it remains stuck until all its non daemon children end. Try that by sleeping longer in its children and monitor processes from another terminal (via `ps -ef`). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604997/why-child-process-daemon-true-not-exiting-when-main-process-exit-in-python/49607291#49607291.

Comment: if main process is killed,  terminal command line is showing. but python doesn't do that. it just keep waiting to something. So I confuse. what is different between C and python daemon process handling...

Comment: if the main process is killed (abnormal exit) then the other children will continue running. Check the answer from my previous comment *URL*. Or wait.... what's your *OS*?