# matplotlib.plot.show continues shows plots even the script finished

Tags: python, matplotlib

**There isn't duplicated answer because I was always blocked by solution below !!!!!!!**

I want to plot a graph and **still run following code without closing the graph automatically like Matlab**.

I try [plt.show(block=False)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13361748/7670016) , it failed and appear in a small moment then close itself.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.plot(range(5), lw=2, label='Real')
    plt.title('Prediction')
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.show(block=False)
    print("---Plot graph finish---")
```

I try [plt.draw() or interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/458295/7670016) , it failed, too. Check the code below.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.plot(range(5), lw=2, label='Real')
    plt.title('Prediction')
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.draw()
    plt.show()
    print("---Plot graph finish---")
```

Above will block until I close it.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.ion()
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.plot(range(5), lw=2, label='Real')
    plt.title('Prediction')
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.draw()
    plt.show()
    print("---Plot graph finish---")
```

Above will appear nothing, or it appear and disappear very fast.

My version is below:

```
user@ya:~/$ sudo pip freeze | grep matplotlib
matplotlib==2.2.3
user@ya:~/$ sudo pip -V
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Environments:

```
I only execute script in Ubuntu ex: user@ya: python xxx.py
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Can anyone help me? I just want to do like Matlab which won't close the plotted graph even if the script finishes.

Comment: @Mr.T I add the env info, but I always run it on Ubuntu.

Comment: @DavidG , No duplicate, because I do it but failed....I have no idea how they achieve that.

Comment: I would be tempted to close this as duplicate as well. The answers over there show precisely how to not block the code execution on showing a figure and the question here does not make it apparent where the difference is.

Comment: @code_worker The only thing that works in my environment is [plt.draw() with plt.pause() such as in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33050617/8881141) or [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40509088/8881141).

Comment: @Mr.T , when your script finish, I guess the graph be closed. But I want the graph kept even the script finished.

Comment: Have you tried these examples? In my environment the figures are opened and updated with `plt.draw/plt.pause` and stay open after the script finishes because of the final `plt.plot`.

Comment: @Mr.T , I tried it, and graph shows 0.01sec(10 * 0.001) and close automatically after script finishes. Maybe keeing graph after script finishing only Matlab can do that.

Comment: Obviously not, because I just wrote that in my environment these two scripts keep the figures open after the script finishes.

Comment: @Mr.T , May I ask your version of matplotlib? maybe the problem of version? Or the environment. Many people test successfully through IPython, but I only can run it in Ubuntu through command line.

Comment: Probably not matplotlib version specific (mine 2.2.3 on Win or 3.0.0 on Ubuntu wiht Eclipse/PyDev) rather that you run it on command line. I would delete this question and ask another one specifically about non-blocking behaviour from the command line. Wouldn't be surprised, if the command line closes the window after finishing the script, but I don't know much about it. Maybe even rather a question for [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)?

Comment: @Mr.T , Ok I should ask another question. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plots will close when the script is finished, even if you use `block=False`

Similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458209/is-there-a-way-to-detach-matplotlib-plots-so-that-the-computation-can-continue), when running from the terminal you have to call `plt.show` at the end of the script to keep these plots open after you've finished. I made a similar code to yours which works as intended; the plot simply refreshes at the end of the code. (added a for loop for a 5 second delay just so you can see it's running).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.plot(range(5), lw=2, label='Real')
    plt.title('Prediction')
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.show(block=False)
    print("---Plot graph finish---")
    for i in range(5):
        print('waiting...{}'.format(i))
        time.sleep(1)
    print('code is done')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, maybe the graph will close after exiting script.

Comment: BTW, the ans of link doesn't solve the problem lol. They will all block the execution of script