# How to make plt.show() nonblocking?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a python3 command line session, once I start `plt.show()`. I can not type any further python3 commands. Is there a way to make `plt.show()` nonblocking?

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.0 (v3.8.0:fa919fdf25, Oct 14 2019, 10:23:27)
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [3, 2, 1]
>>> plt.scatter(x,y)
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x7feb00256670>
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: Duplicate [Is there a way to detach matplotlib plots so that the computation can continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/458209/7758804)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`plt.ion()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ion.html) before `plt.show()` to enable interactive mode.