# Python console in git bash blocked after pyplot.plot()

Tags: python

when I run python (3.10.0) in git bash (python -i) and use the command pyplot.plot() in any variation (of course after importing pyplot), afterwards python seems to be stuck because it ignores all further inputs I type.

If I try 'ctrl + z' I get '0 [sig] bash 1648! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 31372)' (and the console remains stuck) so it seems as if there is an endless process running?

I do not get this when I use another python console, but would be really pleased to be able to continue working in git bash.

Could'nt find a solution via search so hopefully someone here has an idea.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Leonardo

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458209/is-there-a-way-to-detach-matplotlib-plots-so-that-the-computation-can-continue you basically just need to use one of the non-blocking plotting methods, otherwise the blocking behavior is intended

Comment: Hello, yes I saw plenty of remarks about the unblocking use of showing plots online, but unfortunately this is not the solution for my problem because it really isn't with the show() function but with the Plot() itself. After using it I can't even use show(), or any other command.