# How to run a python script so matplotlib plot does not block

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way for a python script to run to completion while backgrounding a `matplotlib` plot? The code below will block until the plot is closed.

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = [0,1,2,3,4]
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

Setting `plt.show(block=False)` prevents the plot from ever showing up.

**Clarification on running**:
From a linux shell, running `python example.py`, which contains the code above, should run and return to the linux prompt while the plot stays up. Currently the plot will block the completion of the python script.

Comment: `plot.show(block=False)` has a simple typo. It should be `plt.show(block=False)`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my question and not my code.

Comment: plt.ion() to be in interactive mode

Comment: I'm using the Jupyter Notebook. There your plot stays open while you can advance in your code. You can also live update it, using sliders and whatnot. Maybe it's helpful to you.

Comment: What is "Is there a way for a python script to run to completion while backgrounding a matplotlib plot?" mean?

Comment: @ConstantinHong presumably he means to have the plot open in the background while continuing whatever else he is doing. Edit: Sorry.

Comment: Will add more clarification to the question. I thought it was clear.

Comment: Once the python process ends, the matplotlib child processes get killed. You will have to save the figure out and open it with an image viewer.

Comment: matplotlib doesn't allow backgrounding the process?

Comment: There isn't anything built into matplotlib but then your question is really about spawning detached child processes, and the answer to that is that usually you can use `multiprocessing`. Example answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56982302/2912349).

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am looking for. It's a shame that this isn't built into matplotlib.